# Define a logger for a specific call hierarchy

Tags: logging, hierarchy

Currently i am working on log4j stuff for my application. I have a specific requirement of logging. I need to **define a logger for a specific call hierarchy**.
Meaning all the log messages of a specific call hierarchy should go to a specific appeneder.

**Example**

AddFormAction(**method1**)  ---|--- FormBusinessObject(**method4**) --|-- FormDAOObject(**method5**)

EditFormAction(method2) -----|---- FormBusinessObject(method4) --|-- FormDAOObject(method5)

DeleteFormAction(method3)----|--- FormBusinessObject(method4) --|-- FormDAOObject(method5)

I want to define a logger for a specific call hierarchy 1 - 4 -5. These messages should goto addform.log.

I don't want the messages from 2-4-5 or 3-4-5 call hierarchies to go to addform.log.

Hope iam clear on my requirement. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks all in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know that much about log4j, but this sounds like a perfect case for [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use injection to give the dependencies their logger instance.

```
 public bool addFormAction( .... form data .... ) {
     Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger( "AddFormLogger" );
     FormBusinessObject form = new FormBusinessObject( logger );
     form.setProperty1( parameter1 );
     form.save();
 }
```

...

```
 public class FormBusinessObject
 {
      private Logger logger;

      public FormBusinessObject() {
          logger = LogManager.GetLogger( "DefaultLogger" );
      }

      public FormBusinessObject( Logger logger ) {
          logger = logger;
      }

      ...

      public void save() {
           logger.info( "Saving form" );
           ...
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but iam injecting the businessobjects through spring so i can't instantiate manually the BO Objects. Any other way to achieve this using Log4j.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Essentially, what you'd need to do is somehow set a global context that would allow you to use a factory of some sort inside your business and DAO objects to obtain the proper logger.  The factory could be injected with Spring.   I'd be tempted to use a singleton context that the factory could just access and return the proper logger.  This would really only work if the application is single-threaded or if the singleton kept track of the context per thread.

Comment: FWIW, everyone I've talked to does logger/class not logger/activity.  Usually, I simply rely on the stack trace to give me the context if I need to know what activity I'm performing.